# Drawing a specific layer from a .dxf file in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using `netDxf`to convert a `.dxf` file to bitmap.
I need to only draw a certain layer on the screen, but I can't find how to iterate through the layers, and then only draw the one I want.

Code to draw the entities:

```
static void DrawDxfEntity(Graphics graphics, EntityObject entity, DxfDocument doc)
{

        if (entity is Line line)
        {
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, (float)line.StartPoint.X, (float)line.StartPoint.Y, (float)line.EndPoint.X, (float)line.EndPoint.Y);
        }
        else if (entity is Circle circle)
        {
            graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, (float)(circle.Center.X - circle.Radius), (float)(circle.Center.Y - circle.Radius),
                (float)(2 * circle.Radius), (float)(2 * circle.Radius));
        }


        else if (entity is Arc arc)
        {
            double sweepAngle = arc.EndAngle - arc.StartAngle;
            arc.EndAngle = sweepAngle;

            if (arc.StartAngle >= 270.565033310362 && arc.StartAngle <= 270.565033310364)
            {
                return;
            }


            graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Black, (float)(arc.Center.X - arc.Radius), (float)(arc.Center.Y - arc.Radius),
            (float)(2 * arc.Radius), (float)(2 * arc.Radius), (float)arc.StartAngle, (float)arc.EndAngle);

        }

        else if (entity is Polyline2D polyline2d)
        {
            if (polyline2d != null)
            {
                var vertexes = polyline2d.Vertexes;

                if (vertexes != null)
                {
                    var points = vertexes.Select(v => new PointF((float)v.Position.X, (float)v.Position.Y)).ToArray();
                    graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, points);
                }
            }

        }
```

I've only figured out how to get the number of layers of the `.dxf` file, and I couldn't get the names/ID of the layers, nor iterate through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
string targetLayerName = "separador"; // Change this to the desired layer name

foreach (var block in dxfDocument.Blocks)
{
    foreach (var entity in block.Entities)
    {
        if (entity.Layer.Name == targetLayerName)
        {
            DrawDxfEntity(graphics, entity);
        }
    }
}
```